# How can I speed up file encryption in C#?

Tags: c#, cryptography, filestream

I'm creating a program that will encrypt files with procedures provided by `System.Security.Cryptography`. For simplicity, I'm just giving a snippet from the encryption method below. The process reads a file in 768MB chunks (`const int CHUNK_SIZE = 768 * 1024 * 1024`) But it takes around 50 seconds to encrypt a file that's over 2GB.

Is there a way to break up this process into more than one thread to encrypt the file data faster? Maybe where each thread reads the next portion of the file?

The CipherMode is `CBC` and Padding is `PKCS7`.

```
using (var rStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    using (var wStream = new FileStream(path + DEFAULT_FILE_EXTENSION, FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write))
    {
        using (var cStream = new CryptoStream(wStream, transformEncrypt, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
            var buffer = new byte[CHUNK_SIZE];
            rStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            int bytesRead = rStream.Read(buffer, 0, CHUNK_SIZE);
            while (bytesRead > 0)
            {
                cStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                bytesRead = rStream.Read(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not totally sure, but this sounds like you could use the new Span<T> or Memory<T> if you are using .Net Core 2.1 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-core-2-1#api-changes

Comment: At least the array resizing seems pointless. Why not just keep the buffer size as it is? Though I don’t expect that to happen more than once per file but still

Comment: You can check to see if the bottleneck is a processor or disk issue by using Task Manager.  If it's the disk, then you are out of luck, if it's a processor that is at 100%, you could possibly thread it, but that depends on if the CryptoStream library supports it (which I doubt).

Comment: What encryption mode are you using, ECB, CBC, CTR or other? Some modes allow parallelism on encryption, others don't. Encryption 2GB is going to take time but on a 4 year old iPhone I see 2GB encryption in under 5 seconds.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen like you said, it trims the buffer so that empty data isn't written to the resulted file.

Comment: But all calls you make take the length as a parameter so it’s not needed

Comment: @zaph currently using CBC with PKCS7 padding

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen maybe I need to refactor then, because when I leave out the resizing, each file < 768MB before processing results in a 768MB file

Comment: Yes, change the cStream.Write() to use bytesRead instead of buffer.Length

Comment: In `CBC` mode you cannot use parallelism since each block affects encryption of the next block.

Comment: Note that CBC mode encrypted data can use parallelism on decryption. ECB mode can use parallelism on encryption but is not secure. CTR mode can be use parallelism on encryption and is secure if as the same initial counter value is never reused. But you should be getting a better encryption rate, what kind of device are you seeing this on and does it have multiple CPU cores?

Comment: You could add the buffers into a `BlockingCollection` and then have a separate thread that consumes the `BlockingCollection` and does the `cStream.Write` calls. The downside is you won't be able to reuse the `buffer` - you'll need to new up an array for each chunk. Whether it is faster or not you'd need to test to confirm.

Comment: Thanks all for your input btw, and @zaph Windows 10 Pro 64bit on AMD FX-4350 Quad-Core 4.20Ghz.

Comment: Does the FX-4350 support the AES-NI instructions, see [AMD x86 architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AES_instruction_set#Intel_and_AMD_x86_architecture).

Comment: @zaph Yeah it seems to be under the [Piledriver-based](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piledriver_(microarchitecture)#Desktop) list

Comment: `Aes.Create()`, `new AesManaged()`, `new RijndaelManaged()`, or something else?

Comment: It's a lot of work, so I probably won't try to implement it but here's how I would try. Create a multithreaded way of filling a contigeous memory space of an AES-CTR key stream (.NET supplies ECB mode which can be used for this, together with counter blocks). Make sure that the AES can use AES-NI where available (see the bartonjs comment above). Create a file with the correct size and memory-map both the input and output file. Now XOR the key stream with the input and write it to the output stream (making sure that you don't XOR faster than the encryption operation).

Comment: @bartonjs [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/meYJuKdu) of my function that returns a new instance of the  chosen algorithm

Comment: Switch to [Algorithm].Create() and you'll suddenly get AES-NI for AES.  Don't use Rijndael, just use Aes.  Boom, faster.

Comment: @bartonjs Wow! Almost twice the speed from `[Algorithm].Create()`! Should I exclude the option to use Rijndael?

Comment: I can encrypt 1 GiB in around 2.2s on my lowly laptop (dual core, hyperthreading, 2.8 GHz turbo) using CTR, the best of my C# FU. That's without I/O, just in-place encryption from RAM to RAM. So you should be able to reach around 500 MiB/s or so. Just to give you a target.

Comment: 4.5s on my laptop to create an encrypted file of the same size, with Windows Defender real time protection turned off (between 6.5s and 18s (!) if it is turned on). I'll let you know when I paste the code on code review, it's my first C# multithreaded application... And yes, I got an SSD in my laptop, of course.

Comment: Make that 4s... still missed a tweak.